# Сделать анимацию кнопки в QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gui

Есть код:

```
   // Button Image
   QImage buttonTexture(":/Theme/button.png");
   auto textureTX = buttonTexture.height()/4;
   QImage defaultTX  = buttonTexture.copy(0, 0 * textureTX, buttonTexture.width(), 1 * textureTX);
   QImage rolloverTX = buttonTexture.copy(0, 1 * textureTX, buttonTexture.width(), 2 * textureTX);
   QImage pressedTX  = buttonTexture.copy(0, 2 * textureTX, buttonTexture.width(), 3 * textureTX);
   QImage lockedTX   = buttonTexture.copy(0, 3 * textureTX, buttonTexture.width(), 4 * textureTX);
```

И сама текстура кнопки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка называется `ui->toLogin`

Как прикрепить изображения к положениям кнопки?

P.S. Названия положений соответствуют названиям положения кнопки в `Java Swing`

Comment: Через установку стиля? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для стилизации компонентов можно использовать `QSS`([Qt Style Sheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html))

`QSS` представляет собой ограниченное подмножество [Каскадных таблиц стилей](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)(`CSS`) и позволяет настраивать внешний вид элементов интерфейса.

Примеры `QSS` Вы сможете найти в [официальной документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)

Для вашей задачи нужно будет разделить изображение фона кнопки на отдельные состояния:

[image: button_0] [image: button_1]
[image: button_2] [image: button_3]

Тогда таблицу стиля для кнопки можно будет описать следующим образом

```css
QPushButton {
    background-image: url(:/Theme/button_0.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-image: url(:/Theme/button_1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-image: url(:/Theme/button_2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
QPushButton:disabled {
    background-image: url(:/Theme/button_3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Псевдоселекторы определяют к какому состоянию будет применяться конкретная запись:

- `:hover` - при наведении мыши
- `:pressed` - кнопка нажата
- `:disabled` - кнопка заблокирована

Хранить таблицу стилей можно двумя способами:

- в строке(подойдет для малого размера)
- в файле(можно прописать в ресурсы)

Рассмотрим второй вариант.
Для этого добавим в ресурсы файл `:/Theme/button.qss` с содержимым указанным выше.

Загрузим этот файл и применим стиль:

```cpp
QFile style_file(":/Theme/button.qss");
style_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)

auto style = QString::fromUtf8(style_file.readAll());

ui->someButton->setStyleSheet(style);
```

Стиль можно так же применить для всего приложения:

```cpp
qApp->setStyleSheet(style);
```

Пример на `Python 3`+`PySide2`

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from typing import List

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


def button_style() -> str:
    return """
    QPushButton {
        background-image: url(theme/button_0.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    QPushButton:hover {
        background-image: url(theme/button_1.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    QPushButton:pressed {
        background-image: url(theme/button_2.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    QPushButton:disabled {
        background-image: url(theme/button_3.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    """


def create_button(text: str, name: str) -> QPushButton:
    b = QPushButton(text)
    b.setObjectName(name)

    b.setFixedWidth(150)
    b.setFixedHeight(47)

    return b


def main(args: List[str]) -> int:
    app = QApplication(args)

    w = QWidget(parent=None)
    w.setWindowTitle("test")
    w.setStyleSheet(button_style())
    box = QVBoxLayout()

    b0 = create_button("btn 0", "btn0")
    b1 = create_button("btn 1", "btn1")
    b2 = create_button("disabled", "btn2")
    b2.setDisabled(True)
    box.addWidget(b0)
    box.addWidget(b1)
    box.addWidget(b2)

    w.setLayout(box)
    w.show()

    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

[image: QPushButton StyleSheet]